# How can you access the class name in a Visual Studio code snippet?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create a code snippet that generates some method that returns an object of the type of the containing class.

More clearly: if I use myCodeSnippet while editing Animal.cs then I want the snippet to generate

```
public Animal someMethod() { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following literal using the built-in function ClassName():

```
        <Literal default="true" Editable="false">
            <ID>classname</ID>
            <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
            <Function>ClassName()</Function>
            <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default>
        </Literal>
```

Then just put $classname$ where you want the class name.

Documentation: [Code snippet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippet-functions?view=vs-2019)